# Why does Google OAuth2 authentication fail when using analytics url instead of youtube url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a dashboard for my colleagues that shows a few stats from Google Analytics next to some other statistics. To get access to the Analytics data I use OAuth2. OAuth2 requires a scope to get send along with the authentication request in order to get access tokens. I created a client ID in the APIs Console that has access to Analytics, and specify the scope in an initializer that looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], { access_type: 'online', approval_prompt: '', scope: 'http://gdata.youtube.com,userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,analytics.readonly' }
end
```

This uses the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem, and the scope I found in an example somewhere. However, for my implementation, I think this scope is strange. Instead of `http://gdata.youtube.com,userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,analytics.readonly` I would like to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly`, but changing to that scope causes the request to return `invalid_credentials`. What is the correct way to specify only access to analytics data is needed?

Comment: Hey Jasper could you copy paste all the info that you have on the `invalid_credentials` error? For instance do you know when it occurs, is it during the initial auth (where you redirect the user to the grant page) or does it happen during the code exchange...

Comment: Tnx for the response Nivco. I'm very busy right now but I'll add the info this evening.

Comment: The error is send along with the redirect to the redirect uri.

Answer (score 3):

Scopes should be seperated by a space character, not a comma:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

if you need Youtube and Analytics scopes use:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], { access_type: 'online', approval_prompt: '', scope: 'http://gdata.youtube.com,userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' }
end
```

if you need just Analytics, use:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['ADMIN_DASHBOARD_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], { access_type: 'online', approval_prompt: '', scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections in my spelling;) Sadly, it seems that the scope you suggest in the second example triggers the error, and I stil don't get why.

Comment: why is approval_prompt blank? Try removing it or setting it to auto. Have you confirmed your Client ID/Secret work if used with the API Explorer? https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ (Click the gear icon at the top right to switch to using your own client id/secret)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out some more:) I found that `approval_prompt` was supposed to be blank somewhere, not really sure where anymore. However adding or removing it doesn't make a difference. I've tested my id and secret in the playground, it works there. That doesn't surprise me because the same credential info does work when authorizing for YouTube AND Analytics.